# java regex match words that aren't numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have a json missing quotes

```
{
    data: [{
        timestamp: 1467720920,
        val: {
            min: 6.90,
            max: 7.25,
            avg: 7.22
        },
        temp: {
            min: 75.49,
            max: 75.49,
            avg: 75.49
        },
        gps: {
            lat: 0.707581,
            long: -1.941864,
            hdop: 2.54,
            ttf: 49.4
        }
    }],
    id: A1000049A6248C,
    groupId: HU5PPC1E,
    rssi: -93,
    cell: {
        timestamp: 1467731669,
        rssi: -93,
        lat: 0.735554,
        long: -1.974655
    }
}
}
```

I need to put quotes around all of the words to the left of the colon and all of the words that aren't purely numbers to the right of the colon.  So I need quotes around A1000049A6248C but not -1.974655. How do I make a regex to do this in java?
I've tried

`json.replaceAll("(\\w+|[+-]([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)", "\"$1\"");`

which will put every word in quotes.  I've also tried something like this to get a word that isn't all numbers `json.replaceAll("\\b(?!\\d*)\\b", "\"$1\"");`

**Expected format**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1463494202,
      "val": {
        "min": 6.75,
        "max": 7.19,
        "avg": 7.14
      },
      "temp_int": {
        "min": 54.28,
        "max": 54.28,
        "avg": 54.28
      },
      "gps": {
        "lat": 0.711407,
        "long": -1.460091,
        "hdop": 1.42,
        "ttf": 42
      }
    }
  ],
  "id": "A1000049A624D1",
  "groupId": "299F7G5AR",
  "rssi": -83,
  "cell": {
    "timestamp": 1463501353,
    "rssi": -83,
    "lat": 0,
    "long": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: A regular expression could do the job, but I have to ask, why? Regular expressions can be very expensive. It looks like you are trying to inject correct formatting into your JSON string, but why isn't it formatted correctly in the first place?

Comment: Its missing quotes, and I need to deal with the numbers as numbers rather than strings, I'm probably just going to put quotes around all the words and use Integer.parseInt()

Comment: I meant why doesn't the strings have quotes already? Do you have any control over how the string is formatted to begin with? If so, why not use a library, like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to generate a correctly formatted string for you?

Comment: I don't have control over how the json is formatted

Comment: Ah, then good luck... and hopefully you can tell whoever *is* in control of that string to do their job right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this lookahead regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\\w-]+(?=\\s*:)", "\"$0\"")
         .replceAll("(?<=:)\\s*(?!-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*(?:,|\\r?\\n))([\\w-]+)", "\"$1\"");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pB6tU8/1)

`(?!-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*(?:,|\\r?\\n))` is the negative lookahead to assert that we're not matching a negative/positive decimal/integer number.

Comment: Thank you, but that only put quotes around words containing both letters and numbers.  I'll play around with it

Comment: If you can show your expected output from above example then I can look into this

Comment: So you want to quote names as well not just the values?

Answer (score 2):

You should use negative lookahead for 'not a number'

```
((?![-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9])\\w+\\b)
```

with 
`\"$0\"` replacement

**Edit:**
JimmyJames solution is probably faster but still need negative lookahead to handle null and boolean values - to handle whole json.

```
\b(?!null|true|false)(\w|\.)*([a-z]|[A-Z])+(\w|\.)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a word is a continuous sequence of word (or period) characters with at least one letter, Wouldn't it me more efficient to do something like this for your match?

```
(\w|\.)*([a-z]|[A-Z])+(\w|\.)
```

As opposed to finding all words and then excluding the numbers?